# How can I know what operators use local resources on a cloud environment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

I'm fairly new to apache airflow, I've some dags running on AWS (Using MWAA) and created a python code to extract data from athena to S3 and use it on redshift.

Now, we are migrating to an EC2 Instance and when I tried running the pipelines, it consumed all the resources and it basically froze the machine. Then I started looking at the specific operators, like the AthenaOperator to run the same queries that I run now, but my question is, this is going to still consume the resources from the EC2 instance to get the data? Like, it gets the data to the instance and then to the S3 bucket or it does using the athena resources?

Would it be better to run a lambda function or create a glue job using airflow as the orchestrator instead of using the operators directly?

I'm sorry about my lack of knowledge on this and about my english, it's not my native language. Any help would be really appreciated, even if it's just a link where I can find the answers to this.

Obs.: The instance I'm using is a t2.medium, we are trying to cut costs, is that enough or should I use a better machine?

Obs².: I managed to run isolated dags on the machine, but when I tried to run them together, that's when the machine wouldn't respond anymore.

Tried to run the same dags from MWAA on an EC2 instance and it froze the whole instance.